# Combining two categorical variables into one in Rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to combine 2 categorical variables into one.
The two variables are called AlcoholicFather and AlcoholicMother. This is from a survey and the variables consistent of yes or no responses. I would like to combine the two variables into one entitled AlcoholicFamilyHistory that show the total of participates with either an AlcoholicMother OR AlcoholicFather.

I am attempting to use the mutate function but not sure if this is appropriate. (I am just barely starting to learn R).

So far I have this:

```
  nesarc_sub %>%
  mutate(AlcoholicFamilyHistory = 
)
```

For reference, here is how I combined two numerical variables:

```
nesarc_sub <-
  nesarc_sub %>%
  mutate(
    Height_inches = Height_ft * 12 + Height_in
  )
```

Any ideas of where to start or where to look for help combining these variables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include a sample of your data.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` should do this for you:

```
nesarc_sub %>%
mutate(AlcoholicFamilyHistory = 
       ifelse( (AlcoholicMother == "Yes")  | (AlcoholicFather == "Yes"), 1, 0))
```

Another option is the `dplyr` function `case_when` which deals with multiple conditionals better and saves having to nest multiple `ifelse` statements.